# Display the result of a custom stock status field in WooCommerce product loop page on the single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have a WooCommerce
and I want to manage several custom stock status like > "delivered into 15 days", "delivered into 7 days".

First, I found this code (I'm not a developer) who let me display "in stock" or "Out of stock" under the add to cart button in product loop page.

```
    //Ajoute "En stock" sous chaque produit
function show_stock() {
global $product;
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') > 0 ) { // if in stock
echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:green;">En stock</div>';
} else {
echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:red;">Rupture</div>'; 
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
```

And it works well.

---

After with some research, I added this

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','show_stock');
```

For display it too in the single product page and I made disappear with CSS the original "in stock" one. And it's okay.

---

Now I found a solution to manage some custom stock messages to display at the same places.
Then I will manage custom stock messages with a specific number of stock.

For example, if I put 1000 stock that will return me "Delivery under 1 month"
If I put 2000 stock that will return me "Delivery under 7 days"

First, I need that WooCommerce stop to manage stock for that my number of the stock stays fixed. 
I will uncheck "manage stock" and put my specific number of stock for that return me my custom message.

I see in the previews code to get the conditional of stock management is

```
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) { // if manage stock is enabled
```

But now I need the opposite, mean conditional is if manage stock is disabled (uncheck)

```
if ( ! $product->managing_stock()
```

So now there my new code yet but something wrong because nothing is displayed if I uncheck manage stock and put 1000 in number of stock

```
        //Ajoute "En stock" sous chaque produit
function show_stock() {
global $product;
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) { // if manage stock is disable
if ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') = 1000 ) { // if stock = 1000 return Livraison sous 7 jours
echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:green;">Livraison sous 7 jours</div>';
}
    elseif ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') = 2000 ) { // if stock = 2000 return Livraison sous 1 mois
echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:#f2cd00;">Livraison sous 1 mois</div>';
}
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
add_action ('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','show_stock');
```

It's because since I don't manage stock I can't take it can't take in count the number of stock?

Comment: _"if I uncheck manage stock and put 1000 in number of stock"_ 
This is not possible... a work-around is to use a custom product field that you will then use as the stocknumber

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Okay i see you mean i just have to manage this system by another product field. Okay i will try.